# Extracting text values from string in batch

Tags: batch-file, text, scripting

I have the following text generated from a batch file:

```
FILE:71.jpg 88557: ( 0, 0, 0) #000000 black 535: ( 0, 0,255) #0000FF blue 3617: ( 0,255, 0) #00FF00 lime 315: ( 0,255,255) #00FFFF cyan 9674: (255, 0, 0) #FF0000 red 214: (255, 0,255) #FF00FF magenta 5552: (255,255, 0) #FFFF00 yellow 11536: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF white
```

and I want to extract the values as follows:

```
8857: black
535: blue
3617: lime
etc..
```

Is there a way that this can be done please? Sorry but I'm not experienced in batch.

Comment: Is that all on one line? How do you know when a color section is done?

Comment: Please regard that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service! Share your efforts and precisely describe what you have problems with! Please read the [tour] and learn how to use this site!

Answer (score 1):

Pressuming that one line string is the only one in file `File.txt`:

```
@Echo off
Set /P String=<File.txt
Set String=%String:(="%
Call :Sub %String:)="%
Goto :Eof
:Sub
shift
If "%~1"=="" Goto :Eof
Echo %1 | findstr "# ," >Nul 2>&1 && goto :sub
Set var=%1
If "%var:~-1%" equ ":" (set /p =%var% <Nul) Else Echo:%1 
goto :Sub
```

Output

```
88557: black
535: blue
3617: lime
315: cyan
9674: red
214: magenta
5552: yellow
11536: white
```

`Set /p` reads one line from file.txt via input redirection.
`%String:(="%` exchanges the parentheses with a double quote to ease parsing.
The shift command skips the first arg and later advances to the next arg.
The findstr in the sub eleminiates unneeded elements.
The if checks if the current argument has a trailing colon, if yes output via set /p with no crlf if not simply echo current arg.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a quite robust script that extracts the colour information from a text file that is provided as command line argument. The text file may even contain multiple lines. The script processes only lines that begin with the literal string `FILE:`, followed by a string that does not contain `:`, `\`, <kbd>SPACE</kbd> (like `71.jpg` in your example). So here is the code, including some explanatory `rem` comments:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1" & rem // (`%~1`: specify input file by command line argument)

rem // Read the input file line by line, split off prefix (`FILE:`):
for /F "tokens=2,* eol=: delims=: " %%K in ('
    rem/ Filter for lines with matching prefix: ^& ^
    findstr /R /C:"^FILE:[^:\\ ][^:\\ ]*  *[0-9][0-9]*:  *" "%_FILE%"
') do (
    rem // Return prefixed file name at `STDERR` stream:
    >&2 echo  **** %%K **** 
    rem // Process current line without prefix in sub-routine:
    call :EXTRACT "%%L"
)

endlocal
exit /B


:EXTRACT  val_string
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Store string argument in variable:
    set "LINE=%~1"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    :EXTRACT_LOOP
    rem // Check whether beginning of string matches a colour block:
    cmd /V /C echo(^^!LINE^^! | (> nul ^
        findstr /R /I /C:"^[0-9][0-9]*:  *( *[0-9][0-9]* *, *[0-9][0-9]* *, *[0-9][0-9]* *)  *#[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]*  *[a-z][a-z]*  *"
    ) && (
        rem // String matches, so continue; extract first number and word:
        for /F "tokens=1,6,* delims=:(,)# " %%A in ("!LINE!") do (
            endlocal
            rem // Return number and word extracted from colour block:
            echo(%%A: %%B
            rem // Assign remainder to variable:
            set "LINE=%%C"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
        rem // Jump back to beginning of loop:
        goto :EXTRACT_LOOP
    )
    endlocal
    endlocal
    exit /B
```

Supposing the batch file is saved as `extract-colours.bat` and the text file is called `sample.txt`, run the script like this:

```bat
extract-colours.bat "sample.txt"
```

If the text file contains your example data, the output is going to be this:

> ```bat
>  **** 71.jpg ****
> 88557: black
> 535: blue
> 3617: lime
> 315: cyan
> 9674: red
> 214: magenta
> 5552: yellow
> 11536: white
> ```

To store the result into another text file, use this comand line:

```bat
extract-colours.bat "sample.txt" > "result.txt"
```

Since the header string portion in between a pair of `****` (`71.jpg` here) is returned at the *STDERR* stream, opposed to the other lines which are output to *STDOUT*, that header is not included in the file; to include it, append `2>&1` to the aforementioned command line; if not, to suppress the header in the console window, append `2> nul` instead. Read this article to learn what all this means: [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).